# Python 3.7 vs Python 2.7 RegEx Matching Behavior

Tags: python, regex

I looked quite a bit on stack overflow for an answer and nothing pops out. It's still not obvious after reading the link provided but I understand.   Perhaps saving this post helps future people who think like I do.

I have reduced my 3.7 vs 2.7 issue down to a very simple code snippet:

```
import re
myStr = "Mary   had a little lamb.\n"
reg_exp = re.compile('[ \\n\\r]*')
reg_exp.split(myStr)

['', 'M', 'a', 'r', 'y', '', 'h', 'a', 'd', '', 'a', '', 'l', 'i', 't', 't', 'l', 'e', '', 'l', 'a', 'm', 'b', '.', '', '']
```

In python 2.7 I get full word tokens.  I would like to modify the compile line to be greedy * without splitting on characters.

If I don't include the greedy * I get extra spaces.

```
reg_exp = re.compile('[ \\n\\r]')
reg_exp.split(myStr)

['Mary', '', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb.', '']
```

I would like to have my cake and eat it too!  This is what I want:

```
['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb.']
```

I've tried all sorts of things like various flags.  I'm missing something very basic.  Can you help?  Thanks!

Comment: Is it Python 3.7? Actually, what output do you want to get in all cases?

Comment: Perhaps you want `+` instead of `*`?  As it is, you're allowing the split to occur wherever there are 0 or more spaces, which is *everywhere*.

Comment: I tried and tried again after your marking as duplicate.   If you would be so kind as to provide the link I could make some progress correctly classifying this question.  I got my answer so I'm glad I asked anyway.....Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### `[ \\n\\r]*` matches empty string

So correct behavior is to split after each letter. Python versions prior to 3.7 ignored empty matches, but version 3.7 fixes that.

You want to replace `*` with `+`

```
reg_exp = re.compile('[ \\n\\r]+')
```

[3.6 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.split), [3.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.split)

Comment: Thank you.   Works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` instead of `*`.

`*` will repeat 0 or more times, so it matches on `""` and splits each character.

`+` will repeat 1 or more times, so it only matches when something is found.